# Scheduled task running as SYSTEM - execute something as current user?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task which runs a batch file which does some stuff. I want the batch file to kick off another batch file which runs in user space; i.e. %username% == the currently logged-in user, with user permissions, etc. How can I run a command under the current user, given that the scheduled task runs with SYSTEM permissions?

I need this for both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note (2013):**  When this answer was posted, I didn't know about `psexec` yet. Using it might be easier.

Ever since the introduction of Terminal Services, "current user" can be plural. Even XP supports fast user switching.

The closest you can get is "user connected to the console session". For this, use [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [WTSQueryUserToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [CreateEnvironmentBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [CreateProcessAsUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

I wrote a program in C# (see attachment below) – Compile, run with full path to your batch file as arguments.

Yes, this requires .NET Runtime, but it's likely that your systems already have it. The compiler's part of the Runtime, too: `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe` (any version starting with `v2.*` will work).

Note: WTSQueryUserToken() requires the program to be running as *LocalSystem*. (According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), *SeTcbPrivilege* is not enough, but I haven't checked.)

---

Attachment: `RunConsole.cs`

```csharp
// (c) 2011 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
// Released under the MIT license <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT>
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class RunConsole {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 sessionId, out IntPtr Token);
    
    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(out IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);
    
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
        IntPtr hToken,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [Flags]
    enum CreateProcessFlags : uint
    {
        CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB           = 0x01000000,
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE           = 0x04000000,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE                  = 0x00000010,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP                = 0x00000200,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW                        = 0x08000000,
        CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS                = 0x00040000,
        CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL    = 0x02000000,
        CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM         = 0x00000800,
        CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM               = 0x00001000,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED                        = 0x00000004,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT          = 0x00000400,
        DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS             = 0x00000002,
        DEBUG_PROCESS                           = 0x00000001,
        DETACHED_PROCESS                        = 0x00000008,
        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT        = 0x00080000,
        INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY             = 0x00010000,
    }
    
    static int Main(string[] argv)
    {
        string cwd = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string appName = argv[0];
        if (appName.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Application not specified.");
        }
        // TODO: Deal with quoted args, etc.
        // For now, good enough to start a .cmd script.
        string commandLine = String.Join(" ", argv);
        
        uint sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();        
        if (sessionId == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No session attached to the physical console.");
        }

        IntPtr hToken;
        if (!WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, out hToken))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        
        IntPtr lpEnvironment;
        if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(out lpEnvironment, hToken, false))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcessAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThreadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
        CreateProcessFlags flags = 0;
        //flags |= CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
        flags |= CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
        
        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, appName, commandLine,
            ref saProcessAttributes, ref saThreadAttributes, false, (uint)flags,
            lpEnvironment, cwd, ref startupInfo, out processInfo))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("pid = {0}", processInfo.dwProcessId);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Under "When Running Task, use the following user account:" you can set it to "BUILTIN\Users" group, it will run the task as the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set it through the task scheduler tool to dynamically use the current logged in user, but you can specify a user account to use besides System in the task itself. Both of the below options will require that you have the password for the username.

Windows 7:
In the properties window for the task, there is a button in Security Options called "Change User or Group".

Windows XP:
In the properties window for the task, you can enter a username in the "Run As" field.

One final option may be to create a startup script that will create the task when the user logs on, and a companion logoff script to delete it when they log off. The command is "Schtasks", which is nearly identical in XP and 7. Documentation for the command is available from MS at the following site:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I'm creating the task via the command line, so I can't change the run as user. Otherwise I would simply check that "run as currently logged on user" box which is terribly convenient! And regarding the logon/logoff script suggestion, that's pretty much what I intend to do, but the schtasks command cannot check the above-mentioned checkbox; it requires an username and password, and I don't want to prompt the user for their password from a script.

Comment: Windows 7 does not seem to have the password entry requirement, at least when I just tried it with UAC off. For XP, you can try using the deprecated AT command instead.

Comment: But the AT command, even with the /interactive flag, runs the command in SYSTEM privileges. I've been testing it just this morning actually and I can't get it to run in the user environment. It seems there are a multitude of ways I could accomplish this in Windows 7, but the big issue at the moment is Windows XP.