# Run Windows 7 Task CMD with SYSTEM user

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, scheduled-tasks

I have a .cmd script I want to run every 5 minutes.

if I add a Windows 7 Task for that it runs fine if I provide a real user.

But I want to run it with the SYSTEM user. Doing this the script does not do anything.

How to fix this?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/257864/scheduled-task-running-as-system-execute-something-as-current-user?rq=1) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can select what user account should be used to run scheduled task in task's properties.

Go to General tab and click to *"Change User or Group..."* button. Type SYSTEM and confirm. The task should start under SYSTEM account after that.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The tasdk runs successfully but nothing happens. If I use a different user, then it works.

Comment: What do you mean by _nothing happens_? What is your script supposed to do?

Comment: My script converts some files, but it doesn't convert any if I use SYSTEM user.

Comment: Try to add "echo whoami > c:\test.txt" to your script. It should write actual user to that file. Just to test whether it was really started under system.